# How to fixandroid.support.v7.widget.AppCompatButton cannot be cast to android.view.ViewGroup

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

I am developing an APP but I found an error in execution , when I try to launch a new Fragment when I click on the button, I try to fix it but I cannot.

The goal is to open a new fragment when I click in a button

SpaceFragment1.java

```
    public class Space1Fragment extends Fragment{


        private Button dss;



        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                                 Bundle savedInstanceState) {

            View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_space1, container, false);



            dss = (Button) v.findViewById(R.id.dss);

            dss.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    Toast.makeText(v.getContext(),"dss",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    LogrosFragment fragment2 = new LogrosFragment();
                    FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
                    FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
                    fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.dss, fragment2);
                    fragmentTransaction.setTransition(FragmentTransaction.TRANSIT_FRAGMENT_OPEN);
                    fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(null);
                    fragmentTransaction.commit();
                }
            });

            return v;
        }

    }
```

fragment_space1

```
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
    app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
    tools:context="com.tfm.miguel.planetaria.Fragments.Space1Fragment"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="25dp"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="0dp">
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/dessi"
        android:visibility="gone"
        android:layout_width="59dp"
        android:layout_height="91dp"
        android:src="@drawable/naranja"
        android:clickable="true"
        tools:ignore="MissingConstraints"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toLeftOf="@+id/ic"
        tools:layout_constraintTop_creator="1"
        tools:layout_constraintRight_creator="1"
        android:layout_marginStart="39dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="37dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="19dp"
        tools:layout_constraintLeft_creator="1"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="@+id/conquista1"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/conquista1"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.285"
        android:layout_marginRight="37dp" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/dss"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:src="@drawable/naranja"
        android:clickable="true"
        tools:ignore="MissingConstraints"
        android:layout_marginEnd="97dp"
        tools:layout_constraintRight_creator="1"
        tools:layout_constraintBottom_creator="1"
        android:layout_marginStart="97dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        tools:layout_constraintLeft_creator="1"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@+id/dessi"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.583"
        android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
        android:onClick="onClick"/>

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/pgpi"
        android:layout_width="67dp"
        android:layout_height="87dp"
        android:src="@drawable/naranja"
        android:clickable="true"
        tools:ignore="MissingConstraints"
        android:layout_marginEnd="109dp"
        tools:layout_constraintRight_creator="1"
        tools:layout_constraintBottom_creator="1"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/tid"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="@+id/conquista2"
        android:layout_marginBottom="26dp"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="208dp" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/ic"
        android:layout_width="72dp"
        android:layout_height="106dp"
        android:src="@drawable/naranja"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:layout_marginStart="55dp"
        tools:ignore="MissingConstraints"
        android:layout_marginEnd="53dp"
        tools:layout_constraintTop_creator="1"
        tools:layout_constraintRight_creator="1"
        tools:layout_constraintBottom_creator="1"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/dss"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="@+id/pgpi"
        android:layout_marginTop="135dp"
        tools:layout_constraintLeft_creator="1"
        android:layout_marginBottom="138dp"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/pgpi"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@+id/cc" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/tid"
        android:layout_width="117dp"
        android:layout_height="111dp"
        android:src="@drawable/naranja"
        android:clickable="true"
        tools:ignore="MissingConstraints"
        tools:layout_constraintRight_creator="1"
        tools:layout_constraintBottom_creator="1"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        tools:layout_constraintLeft_creator="1"
        android:layout_marginBottom="156dp"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@+id/pgpi"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="267dp" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/cc"
        android:layout_width="69dp"
        android:layout_height="153dp"
        android:src="@drawable/naranja"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:layout_marginStart="26dp"
        tools:ignore="MissingConstraints"
        tools:layout_constraintTop_creator="1"
        android:layout_marginTop="19dp"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/ic"
        tools:layout_constraintLeft_creator="1"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent" />

    <ImageView
        android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
        android:id="@+id/conquista1"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        android:paddingRight="20dp"
        android:paddingBottom="50dp"
        android:scaleX="1.2"
        android:scaleY="1.2"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:src="@drawable/mundo01"
        tools:layout_constraintTop_creator="1"
        tools:layout_constraintRight_creator="1"
        tools:layout_constraintBottom_creator="1"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/cc"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"

        tools:layout_constraintLeft_creator="1"

        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/pgpi" />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

The error is:

```
        06-17 08:33:16.056 2403-2403/com.tfm.miguel.planetaria E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                                 Process: com.tfm.miguel.planetaria, PID: 2403
                                                                                 java.lang.ClassCastException: android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatButton cannot be cast to android.view.ViewGroup
                                                                                     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransition.configureTransitionsUnoptimized(FragmentTransition.java:284)
                                                                                     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransition.startTransitions(FragmentTransition.java:113)
                                                                                     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executeOpsTogether(FragmentManager.java:2146)
                                                                                     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.optimizeAndExecuteOps(FragmentManager.java:2103)
                                                                                     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:2013)
                                                                                     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl$1.run(FragmentManager.java:710)
                                                                                     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751)
                                                                                     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                                                                                     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
                                                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6077)
                                                                                     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                                     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:866)
                                                                                     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:756)
```

Answer (score 4):

The problem is in this line

```
fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.dss, fragment2);
```

`R.id.dss` is the id of your button, where as what you are trying to do is replace fragment which is View, that is why you are getting error.

Comment: To clarify, a button is NOT a ViewGroup, as such, you cannot add and remove children from it, which is what fragmentTransaction.replace will try to do.

Answer (score 1):

Read **[Nested Fragments](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/android-4.2.html#NestedFragments)**

> With Android 4.2 APIv17 there was support for Nested Fragments Where
>   you can use fragment inside other fragment.

Create a **FrameLayout** above End tag of **ConstraintLayout**   .

```
    <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/child_fragment"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" />

 </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Then put ***FrameLayout*** `ID` **child_fragment** in  **`fragmentTransaction.replace`** Section .

```
 LogrosFragment fragment2 = new LogrosFragment();
                FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
                FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
                fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.child_fragment, fragment2);
                fragmentTransaction.setTransition(FragmentTransaction.TRANSIT_FRAGMENT_OPEN);
                fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(null);
                fragmentTransaction.commit();
```

Comment: Ok, I get it, but when I push the button, my new fragment is not appear,how can I can solve?

Comment: @NeosFV use `fragmentTransaction.add` instead of `replace`

Comment: I used fragmentTransaction.add to change my fragment Space1 to LogrosFragment both of them are into Tab Menu, I put                  fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.logrosChild, fragment2);

Comment: I used fragmentTransaction.add to change my fragment **Space1Fragment **to **LogrosFragment** both of them are into Tab Menu,I put                  `fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.logrosChild, fragment2);` where R.id.logrosChild was added in my fragment_logros.xml but when I click appear me this error `                                                                         java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No view found for id 0x7f0d0095 (com.tfm.miguel.planetaria:id/logrosChild) for fragment LogrosFragment{53ede1 #3 id=0x7f0d0095}
`